# How can I refactor my code to resolve lint error?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, refactoring, karma-jasmine

I have been writing test cases for switch case and there are 2 test cases. I am getting this lint error saying `Update or refactor this function so that its implementation does not duplicate other`. As the switch cases conatins similar cases I need help to refcator my code..

Here is my 2 cases

```
  it('case 1', () => {
    data = merge(Run.String_Window, {
      0: '3',
    });
    expect(service.getName('year-1', element, frequency)).toEqual(serve);
  });

  it('case 2', () => {
    data = merge(Run.String_Window, {
      0: '5',
    });
    expect(service.getName('year-2', element, frequency)).toEqual(serve);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the same test for multiple values then you can create an array where each item contains your input data and your expected data. You can then loop over that array and execute your test for each data set:

```
const testCases = [
  {
    desc: 'case 1',
    input: { /* ... */ },
    expected: { /* ... */ }
  }, {
    desc: 'case 2',
    input: { /* ... */ },
    expected: { /* ... */ }
  }
  // case 3,4,5....
];

testCases.forEach(tc => {
  it(tc.desc, () => {
    //...
    expect(/*...*/).toEqual(tc.expected);
  });
});
```

Comment: It says to define a constant instead of duplicating literal when I write case 2

Comment: You shouldn't be getting that error by adding another entry in the array. Can you show us what you are doing? I have slightly updated my answer in case it wasn't clear.